# html5 d3d application menus/hud

Tags: c++, webkit, direct3d

I'm looking to use html5/css/js for the menu system and hud of a C++ d3d application. Ideally I'd like a 64bit MSVC10 library that I can statically link to.

So far I'm looking at:

- [Berkelium](http://berkelium.org/_window_delegate_8hpp_source.html)
- [chromiumembedded](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)
- [QtWebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit)
- [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/)

Before I commit alot of time I'd like to understand the which library would be the best for my purposes (not just from the list above). Could I use WebKit directly? Or chromium?

Even though this concept seems to be catching on right now I can hardly find a single example showing how to do it or collating relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

You may also look at GUI toolkits that embed/integrate/have plugins for your listed HTML renderers (MyGUI comes to mind, with Berkelium/Awesomium integration).

Berkelium or Awesomium in general are probably a good bet, they're rather widely used for embedding Webkit and will work well. Berkelium is somewhat newer, and may have a few less features, but documentation tends to be better.

Of note is the long history Awesomium's developers have of flip-flopping licenses and suddenly trying to get money out of users (they've had free licenses before, which then were retconned into a pay-when-you-release), so that should be taken into careful consideration before touching it.

I'm not familiar with chromiumembedded and Qt has gone heavily OpenGL, severely damaging its value in graphics apps in general and likely making it useless to you.